# Associative Law for a Monoid in a Monoidal Category.

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $B$ be a monoidal category, and $c$ a monoid in $B$. Powers of $c$ are defined by taking $c^{n}$ to be the $\otimes $-string of length $n$ of $c$ in which the parentheses are all in front.

We have a multiplication using $\mu$ defined by taking

$\mu _{e}=\eta, \mu _{c}= 1_{c}, \mu _{c\otimes c}=\mu $ and thereafter $\mu _{u_{c}\otimes v_{c}}=\mu(\mu _{u_{c}}\otimes \mu _{v_{c}})$

Then, the multiplication is, using the notation for powers of $c$,

$\mu ^{0}= \eta $, $\mu ^{1}=1_{c}$, $\mu ^{2}=\mu $, and thereafter, $\mu ^{n+1}=\mu \left ( \mu ^{n} \otimes 1\right )$.

Let $k_{1},k_{2},\cdots, k_{n}$ be any set of $n$ integers.

Then, we have $c^{k_{1}+k_{2}+\cdots +k_{n}}\overset{\phi }{\longrightarrow} ((c^{k_{1}}\otimes c^{k_{2}})\otimes \cdots \otimes c^{k_{n}})\overset{\mu '}{\longrightarrow}c$, where $\phi $ is the canonical map given by coherence, and $\mu '$ is $\mu _{ c_{k_{1}}\otimes c_{k_{2}}\otimes c_{k_{3}}\otimes \cdots \otimes c_{k_{n}}}$, with all the parentheses in the front. We then have the well.known result

$1)$. $\mu '\phi =\mu ^{k_{1}+k_{2}+\cdots +k_{n}}$

Now, Mac Lane has a formula for this situation: $\mu ^{n}(\left ( \mu ^{k_{1}} \otimes \mu ^{k_{2}}\right )\otimes \cdots \mu ^{k_{n}})=\mu ^{k_{1}+k_{2}+\cdots +k_{n}}$.

My problem is, when I work out the LHS of this equation, it turns out to be $\mu '$, which  contradicts eqn $1)$.

Where is my mistake?

Edit: To show my work, It's induction on $n$:

if $n=0$ the result is trivial. In what follows, all strings of $\otimes $ are assumed to have all parentheses in front.

Then $\mu ^{n+1}(\mu ^{k_{1}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mu ^{k_{n+1}})=(\mu (\mu ^{n}+1))(\mu ^{k_{1}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mu ^{k_{n+1}})$ by definition of the multiplication.

This is equal to $\mu [\mu ^{n}(\mu ^{k_{1}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mu ^{k_{n}})\otimes \mu^{k_{n+1}}]$ because $\otimes $ is a bifunctor.

Now apply the inductive hypothesis to write this as

$\mu [(\mu _{ c_{k_{1}}\otimes c_{k_{2}}\otimes c_{k_{3}}\otimes \cdots \otimes c_{k_{n}}})\otimes \mu  ^{k_{n}+1}]$, and now and noting that $\mu ^{k_{n}+1}$ is just $\mu _{c^{k_{n}+1}}$ we may appeal to the definition of the multiplication again, to write $\mu _{ c_{k_{1}}\otimes c_{k_{2}}\otimes c_{k_{3}}\otimes \cdots \otimes c_{k_{n+1}}}$.

Comment: Mac lanes formula is for strict categories I believe.

Comment: Could you show how you worked it out?

Comment: @PyRulez: please see my edit. I am beginning to think that this formula only works for strict monoidal categories, as you say, especially since, later on, Maclane proves that $\left \langle \triangle ,+,0 \right \rangle$ is universal among strict monodal categories, in which he uses this formula. There does not seem to be any other restriction on strictness for the proof to go through,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it might be that Mac Lane made a small error (gasp!) This error can be seen simply by seeing the domain and codomain don't match up. $$\mu^{k_1 + k_2 + ... + k_n}:c \otimes c \otimes \dots \otimes c \space (k_1+\dots+k_n \text{times}) \to c$$
$$\mu(\mu^{k_1} \otimes \mu^{k_2} \otimes \dots \otimes \mu^{k_n}):(c \otimes \dots \otimes c \space (k_1 \text{times})) \otimes (c \otimes \dots \space (k_2 \text{times})) \otimes \dots \otimes (c \otimes \dots (k_n \text{times})) \to c$$

This is actually quite a subtle error, since it relies on [evil](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence) concepts; the two morhpisms are equal "up to canocial isomorphism" after all. Given the context though, it does seem to be an error, since we are specifically discussing this morhpisms.